# KVO and changing UI on value changed

Tags: objective-c, ios, thread-safety, key-value-observing

If I add an observer to observe the "highlighted" property of a UILabel, can I make a change to another UIView within the observation callback block? ie: Am I guaranteed that this callback block will always execute on the main thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will receive the `observeValueForKeyPath:...` message on the thread that changes the property you're observing.

UIKit only supports changing a view's properties on the main thread.  As long as you follow that rule, you will only be notified on the main thread.

If you need to change the label's `highlighted` property from another thread, you should dispatch to the main thread to do it.  For example, you can do this safely from any thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    myLabel.highlighted = YES;
});
```